# Allow tags in Select2 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have tried to enabled tags on select2 elements when they have a specific class

```
$(".select2Tags").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).select2({
        tags: true
    });
});
```

But allowing new tags is not working. How can I make that work?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: Or better yet, a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) so others don't have to go to a separate site just to understand the question?

Comment: Your wording is implying that you're trying to enable tags on elements that have already had select2 initialised. Is this the case?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you forgot to set `multiple` attribute to the select element?

```js
$(".select2Tags").each(function(index, element) {
  $(this).select2({
    tags: true,
    width: "100%" // just for stack-snippet to show properly
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <select class="select2Tags" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">orange</option>
    <option>white</option>
    <option selected="selected">purple</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected:

**HTML**

```
<select id="example" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
<button id="btnTest" />

</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('#example').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a month'
});

$('#btnTest').on('click', function() {
    $('#example').select2({
         multiple: true,
         tags:true;
    });
})
```

**Working snippet**

https://jsfiddle.net/b6p3oycd/

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation of the `select2` plugin one can read:

> In addition to a pre-populated menu of options, Select2 can dynamically create new options from text input by the user in the search box. This feature is called "tagging". To enable tagging, set the tags option to true.

And

> Note that when tagging is enabled the user can select from the pre-existing options or create a new option by picking the first choice, which is what the user has typed into the search box so far.

First, you can check next basic examples of how to use this feature. If a `select2` have the `tags` option enabled, it will let you create a new temporary tag using the search box. When you create a new tag, and after that, you select a new option, the previous created tag will disappear since they are not permanently added as a new option on the select.

## Basic examples:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Initialize first select without using tags.

    $(".select2").select2(
    {
        placeholder: 'Select an option'
    });

    // Initialize second select with tags enabled.

    $(".select2tag").select2(
    {
        placeholder: 'Select an option',
        tags: true
    });

    // Initialize third select with tags and multiple options enabled.

    $(".select2tagMultiple").select2(
    {
        tags: true,
        multiple: true
    });
});
```

```css
select {
    width: 90vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<h3>Select without tags:</h3>
<p>You are only able to select one of the available options</p>
<select class="select2">
  <option></option>
  <option value="FR">France</option>
  <option value="DE">Germany</option>
  <option value="IT">Italy</option>
  <option value="ES">Spain</option>
  <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
</select>
<br>

<h3>Select with tags enabled</h3>
<p>You can select from the pre-existing options or create a new option by picking the first choice, which is what the user has typed into the search box so far</p>
<select class="select2tag">
  <option></option>
  <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
  <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
  <option value="CL">Chile</option>
  <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
  <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
</select>
<br>

<h3>Select with tags and the multiple option enabled</h3>
<p>You can select from the pre-existing options or create a new option by picking the first choice, which is what the user has typed into the search box so far. This also enables the possibility to create multiple tags.</p>
<select class="select2tagMultiple">
  <option value="D">Dog</option>
  <option value="C">Cat</option>
  <option value="B">Bird</option>
  <option value="H">Horse</option>
  <option value="F">Frog</option>
</select>
```

However, I can guess that none of the previous examples going to satisfy your question. For the poor redaction you have made, I assume what you want is **1)** dynamically enable/disable the `tags` options or **2)** a **non-multiple** select with the `tags` option enabled that let you add more than one new `tag`.

## 1) Approach for dynamically enable/disable tags.

If you need to enable/disable the tags options on the select dynamically, then just re-initialize the plugin as shown on the next snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Initialize an standard select2.

    $(".select2").select2(
    {
        placeholder: 'Select an option'
    });

    // Register a listener on the change event of checkbox for
    // dynamically enable/disable the tags option.

    $("#cbTags").change(function()
    {
        var cfg = {
            placeholder: 'Select an option'
        };

        if ($(this).is(":checked"))
            cfg.tags = true;

        $(".select2tag").select2(cfg);
    });
});
```

```css
select {
    width: 90vw;
}

.custom {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="select2 select2tag">
  <option></option>
  <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
  <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
  <option value="CL">Chile</option>
  <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
  <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
</select>
<div class="custom">
  <label><b>Enable Tags</b></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbTags">
</div>
```

## 2) Approach for enable multiple tags creation.

Bind a listener to the `change` event. The `select2` plugin adds an attribute called `data-select2-tag` to the options that are created using the tags feature. These options are deleted when you change to other available option (i.e are temporaries). So, on every `change` event we going to delete those attributes to cheat the plugin an prevent it to delete. You can check the next code:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Initialize the select with tags enabled.

    $(".select2tag").select2(
    {
        placeholder: 'Select an option',
        tags: true
    });

    // Register a listener on the change event.

    $(".select2tag").change(function()
    {
        $(this).find("option").removeAttr("data-select2-tag");
    });
});
```

```css
select {
    width: 90vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="select2tag">
  <option></option>
  <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
  <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
  <option value="CL">Chile</option>
  <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
  <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
</select>
```

Anyway, you should note that these new created `tags` will be only available on the **client-side** (without refreshing the browser). If you want to preserve these new `tags` into the **server-side** for future access, then you will need a better approach, like, for example:

**(1)** Capture a new `tag` on creation.

**(2)** Validate the tag name (you don't want to store all the user can write).

**(3)** If tag is valid, then send to the server and store on some structure (maybe a database).

**(4)** Reload the `select` with the new set of data.

But this will require much more code, and knowing details of your environment, so it is beyond the scope of this response.

Comment: a great explanation, however i don't think it answers my question and problem as to why its not working

Comment: @charlie, if you improve your question, there will be a more accurate answer, right now it is some way unclear what is not working or what you really want.

Comment: the tags are not working, its only allowing me to select the listed options and not create new

Comment: Have you checked the **Basic Examples** section of my answer, in that section (if you run the snippet examples) the `tags` works, like in all other examples. Please, can you provide the code you have showing the issue, in a reproducible way, so we can check what mistake are you making?

Comment: There is a lot of useless code for the OP question in this answer. May be cleaning it up will make it more clear and coincise.

Comment: @AntonioBuelli this is because the question is not clear at all, so I made more than one approach assuming what he would need. I'm not going to delete anything because it took me a lot of effort and time making this answer. It is your opinion, for other people, this can be useful.